# How to correctly use ExAllocatePoolWithTag so that it doesn't return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, kernel, driver

I am writing kernel-mode tests for an IO filter driver. When I run my tests they all pass, but if I run them 3 times in a row, the tests start to fail. I narrowed the issue to [`ExAllocatePoolWithTag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which after some time starts returning `STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`. To reproduce the problem I wrote a dedicated test

```
static void __stdcall TestFoo_StressLoad()
{       
    int i;      
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        CFIX_ASSERT(QueueInitialize() == 0); // Soon returns STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
        CFIX_ASSERT(QueueDestroy() == 0);   
    }
}
```

My pattern of use is:

1. Allocate memory (`ExAllocatePoolWithTag`)
2. Perform single test
3. Release memory (`ExFreePoolWithTag`)

**My question is: How to correctly use [`ExAllocatePoolWithTag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so that it doesn't return `STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`?**

Here is an extract for the `QueueInitialize` and `QueueDestroy`

```
int QueueInitialize()
{
    SIZE_T poolSize;    
    poolSize = sizeof(Event) * 1024;
    Queue = (Event *)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, poolSize, '9gaT');

    if( Queue == NULL )
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

    return 0;
}

int QueueDestroy()
{   
    SIZE_T poolSize;
    if(Queue != NULL)
    {       
        poolSize = sizeof(Event) * 1024;
        ExFreePoolWithTag((void *)Queue, '9gaT');
        ProcessQueue = NULL;
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

I am using cfix for kernel tests and running tests on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Might it simply be too big for the non-paged pool?  What is `sizeof(Event)`?

Comment: @HarryJohnston the `poolSize = 1335296` and `sizeof(Event) = 1,304`. It indeed looks too big and I've never realised this... If I reduce the size of event, which I think I could do, to a few KB will that allow me to reuse `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` multiple times for my tests? Tnx.

Comment: That's only a bit more than a megabyte.  I wouldn't have thought that was too much.  (Task Manager on my machine shows the total non-paged pool size at 137MB.)  But I don't know what else could be going wrong, it might be worth a try at any rate.  You could also try allocating the memory once at driver initialization and reusing it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using lookaside lists since you buffers are always the same size. This will reduce kernel heap fragmentation significantly.

Comment: I would guess that under normal circumstances (i.e., not during testing) this would be undesirable - it means the driver would be taking up valuable non-paged memory that it didn't actually need, possibly for long periods of time.  I suppose it might be possible to use a different memory allocator during testing, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Depends on the size of the queue, the size of the items, and how frequently it is used. I would guess this memory is insignificant unless the queue is holding huge items. If it is a IRP queue or something similar where only small values such as pointers are used, it is preferable over ExAllocXxx(). I have used them in many drivers and have never had an issue with memory.